# Maximum of range

Tags: excel, vba, range, max

I am using excel vba, I have a column with sequences of numbers that are limited by a word at the beggining of the sequence and by a blank cell at the end. 
(i.e. Kip 1 2 3 4 5 "blank cell" Kip 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 "blank cell"...)

I am trying to obtain the maximum of each sequence of numbers by doing this but it is not working. Could somebody help me solve the problem?

`

```
Sub Maxim()

Dim rg1 As Range

Dim rg2 As Range

Dim i As Integer

For i = 12 To 70000

If (Cells(i, 5) = "kip") Then
Set rg1 = Range(Cells(i + 1, 5))
End If

If (Cells(i, 5) = "") Then
Set rg2 = Range(Cells(i - 1, 5))
Cells(i, 7) = Max(rg1, rg2)
End If

Next i
End Sub
```

`

P.S. I am new coding in VBA

Thank you

Comment: Does it have to be vba?  It can be done with a formula.

Comment: the formula is fine too, but I think it will only work for one sequence of numbers and i will have to specify the range

Comment: can also post a screenshot sample of the data? That will help us write a good formula or vba code if needed without too much trial and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following formula in G1:

```
=IF(E1="Kip",MAX(INDEX($E1:$E$500,MATCH("Kip",$E1:$E$500,0)+1):INDEX($E2:$E$500,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($E2:$E$500="",0),0)-2)),"")
```

and copied down.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thank you for your answer Scott! I m trying to figure out how to upload a screenshot of my data.. But what you have is almost what I got on my sheet, except that the word kip in in the same column that the numbers.
Will this modify your formula?

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your help

Comment: @user5965221 made a slight modification to the formula based on your screen shot.